# An opposite for apocryphal?

Tags: meaning

We say apocryphal when something is well known, but is probably not true.

I was just wondering if there is a word that describes something that is widely known as only "a rumour" but is probably really true. Is there such a word?

Comment: "Believable" isn't quite what you are looking for is it?

Comment: I cannot think of a single instance of such a thing existing in the real world (unless you include conspiracists, of course) … so I highly doubt there’s a word for it.

Comment: Not 'pocryphal'?

Comment: @Janus: I think the concept of a [generally unrecognized  fact](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22generally+unrecognized++fact%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is reasonably familiar to most people. We just don't have a *single* word for it (probably). But in some contexts, ***unverified*** might fit the bill.

Comment: Area 51 perhaps?

Comment: @Fumble A generally unrecognised fact is something different to me: a fact that is true (or at least claimed to be true), but that not many people know about. What the asker here is looking for is something that is widely recognised to be false, but which is in fact true. I can't think of any instances of that at all, except perhaps Area 51 as medica says (but then that's so shrouded in secrecy it's hard to know what really is and isn't true about it at all).

Comment: @Janus: It rather depends where you live, but I'm sure Turkey isn't the only country where [the majority don't believe humans developed from earlier species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Views_on_Evolution.svg). And I don't know what "Mainline Protestant" means in the US, but apparently [only 51% of them accept that premise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_support_for_evolution) (only 52% of Americans *as a whole*). So I'd say for many the "theory" of evolution qualifies as a *"generally unacknowledged **fact**"*.

Comment: @Fumble Good example! And the phrasing _generally **unacknowledged** fact_ seems much more apposite to me: it does not imply that people are simply unaware of the fact altogether, but rather that people are aware of it, but reject it.

Comment: Not exactly what you're after, but Terry Pratchett coined the word [substition](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/index.php/Substition) for something that is true but not widely believed (an antonym of "superstition").  It's in the urban dictionary but doesn't really seem to have caught on ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally, *apocryphal* is taken as being antonymous to *canonical*; there is a *canon* that is accepted (whether the biblical canon, or a "canon of lore"), and outside of that is the *apocrypha* which is uncanonical.

This refers solely to how accepted each is, not that either is true or untrue, and indeed even in the figurative use you refer to, such apocrypha can still be true, we just don't have much evidence to prove it. Most such is probably false, because there's a lot of people making up a lot of things (even before social media and meme-generator websites), but some such things are true statements where the supporting evidence is forgotten (the problem is we don't know which they are).

For the meaning you are looking for, where the fact is true but not widely believed, I can't think of a perfect match right now, *little-known* and *widely-disbelieved* hit part, but not all of the target. A case could be made for *occult*, but that word has long been associated only with a particular type of hidden fact, and for that matter with many things that are neither facts, nor particularly well-hidden.

Answer (score 1):

A few words come to my mind right away:

- Religious context I would use *tenet*.
- Scientific context I would use *hypothesis*.
- Everyday usage I would use (conspiracy) *theory*.

Answer (score 1):

A [***postulate***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/postulate) is

> something taken as self-evident or assumed without proof as a basis for reasoning.

Comment: The OP wants an adjectival form, which might be "axiomatic."

Comment: @BenCrowell- very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *credible.* A credible witness is not merely one whom we *can* believe but one whom we probably *ought* to believe. The adjective can also be applied to the testimony of such a witness.

M-W: “offering reasonable grounds for being believed”

OED:

> **A.** *adj.* 
> **1.a.** Able to be believed in, justifying confidence; convincingly honest, principled, or authentic and often, as a corollary, accurate (passing into sense A. 1b); trustworthy, reliable.
>
> (a) Of information, evidence, etc.
>
> (b) Of a person, source of information, etc.
>
> **b.** Able to be believed; convincingly true or accurate.
>
> (a) Of an assertion, account, etc.

Comment: ‘Credible’ does not imply that people in general _don’t_ believe it, though.

Comment: Is that implication really among the OP's desiderata? The placement of the quotation marks / inverted commas (so as *not* to include *only),* and the use of the word *probably* (rather than *actually)* led and lead me to believe otherwise. Am I mistaken, @gagaism ?